# Достать код из Eclipse

Tags: windows, java, eclipse

Пишу диплом в Eclipse. Нужно достать код всех классов из него для отчета. Можно ли это как-то быстро сделать?
OS Microsoft Windows

Comment: Задача по сути ничем не отличается от считывания данных с файла. Напишите код, который будет как-то "собирать" коды всех классов куда-то, откуда потом можно будет скопировать в отчет.   
Хотя, мне кажется, что, если кода немного, то лучше просто исходники прикрепить, чем вставлять куда-то код..

Comment: @Stas0n исходники прикрепить не получится, потому что это диплом.

Comment: @Мария_1, никогда не понимал стремление людей вставлять строки кода в текст диплома.. А кода много?

Comment: для дипломов есть требования и их нужно выполнять.

Решение проблемы - использование tex. Там это все решается очень просто.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку вы не написали ОС, вот вам для Linux'а:

```
find /src/dir -name '*.java' | while read f; do echo $f; cat "$f"; done >report.txt
```

---

Поскольку я не спец в Java, вот вам однострочник на C#:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "report.txt"
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.java", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .SelectMany(f => new[] { f }.Concat(File.ReadLines(f))));
```

Comment: @VladD поправила вопрос. Это не линукс(

Comment: @Мария_1: поправил ответ.